# Using sftp outbound gateway to get a list of files from a remote directory

Tags: spring, spring-integration, sftp

I am trying to do something that I feel is relatively simple and straightforward. I am trying to get a list of files from a specific remote directory, and then figure out what I want to do with the files based on the date.

The issue that I am having is that once the sftp connection is made, and the ls command executes, it seems to always return files from the root directory "/", rather than going to the remote-directory that I have specified. I have tried various iterations of remote-directory, and or expression to get at files from the directory that I want to no avail.

I wish to retrieve files from the remote directory:
"/sites/cmsftp/site/live/ftp/cmsoss/outbound"

The configuration is:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="remoteftpLS"
                           session-factory="dealerDataSftpSessionFactory"
                           request-channel="sftpRequestChannel"
                           command="ls"
                           remote-file-separator="/"
                           remote-directory="/sites/cmsftp/site/live/ftp/cmsoss/outbound"
                           expression="''"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           local-directory="${ftpOutputPath}"
                           reply-channel="fileListSplitterInputChannel" />
```

I have also tried:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="remoteftpLS"
                           session-factory="dealerDataSftpSessionFactory"
                           request-channel="sftpRequestChannel"
                           command="ls"
                           remote-file-separator="/"
                           remote-directory="/sites/cmsftp/site/live/ftp/cmsoss/outbound"
                           expression="payload"
                           charset="UTF-8"
                           local-directory="${ftpOutputPath}"
                           reply-channel="fileListSplitterInputChannel" />
```

There are no errors here. The first way that I discovered that it was always going to root was when I placed an expression to look for files named a particular way and noticed that I got back an exception stating that there was no such file. Only then did I change the expression to payload, or "''", which returned me a list of files from the root directory. Stopping at a breakpoint in the custom splitter that is downstream from this gateway is how I verified that it is pulling files from the root directory.

Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 1):

you can using a gateway
For Example:

```
package org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp; // sample
/**
 * @author Gary Russell
 * @since 2.1
 *
 */
public interface ToFtpFlowGateway {
    public List<Boolean> lsGetAndRmFiles(String dir);
}
```

and in xml file:

```
<int:gateway id="gw" service-interface="org.springframework.integration.samples.ftp.ToFtpFlowGateway"
        default-request-channel="sftpRequestChannel"/>
```

and finally:

```
List<Boolean> results = toFtpFlow.lsGetAndRmFiles("/sites/cmsftp/site/live/ftp/cmsoss/outbound");
```

please see [ftp sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/basic/ftp)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<int-sftp:outbound-gateway id="remoteftpLS"
                       session-factory="dealerDataSftpSessionFactory"
                       request-channel="sftpRequestChannel"
                       command="ls"
                       remote-file-separator="/"
                       expression="'/sites/cmsftp/site/live/ftp/cmsoss/outbound'"
                       charset="UTF-8"
                       local-directory="${ftpOutputPath}"
                       reply-channel="fileListSplitterInputChannel" />
```

From reference manual:

> For all commands, the PATH that the command acts on is provided by the 'expression' property of the gateway. For the mget command, the expression might evaluate to '*', meaning retrieve all files, or 'somedirectory/*' etc.

Comment: Thanks. That is ultimately exactly what I did to get things working. I think I was trying to do to many things with the LS. I wanted initially to list only files that conformed to a specific pattern, like "CMS_*.csv". So I figured I would use LS as it was intended, and just filter the results afterward.    

Thanks guys for your help. It became kinda obvious when I stepped into the spring integration source.